# SQL how to INSERT a row for user when i only have login, not the id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

> Users (idk, surnamek, namek, logink)
>
> Measurements (idm, date, weight, #idk)

How can I use INSERT to add a row to measurements for a particular user if I only have 'logink' from Users table? I am using postgresql

sample data:

Users:

```
(1, Smith, Tom, tomsmith)

(2, Pitt, Brad, pittbrad)
```

Measurments:

```
(1, 19.02.2019, 80, 1)

(2, 19.07.2019, 85, 1)
```

after the INSERT i would like Measurments to be like:

```
(1, 19.02.2019, 80, 1)

(2, 19.07.2019, 85, 1)

(3, 19.08.2019, 88, 1)
```

after giving 'tomsmith' as login

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Also mention which DBMS you are using.

Comment: maybe try to create sequence, and then use NEXTVAL() function? all depends from which database you are using

Comment: using postgresql, edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the user id from the `Users` table when inserting. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Measurements(idm, date, weight, idk)
SELECT @idm,
       @date,
       @weight,
       ud.idk
FROM   Users u
WHERE  u.logink = @logink
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
INSERT INTO Measurements (idm, date, weight, logink)
VALUES (...,...,..., (SELECT idk FROM Users WHERE logink = 'your value'));
```